# Mvc, Jquery, Chosen. Dependent Dropwdowns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

help to solve a problem:
in my mvc project, i have two checked dropdown lists (dropdown with checkboxes)
i need to do: after selecting item in first dropdown list, the secon is filtered (better filled) according to selected item in first.

I got filtered data by getJSON, by i can not refresh dropdown.

Here is my code:

(there is similar question, by i did not foud solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239795/how-to-add-multiple-dependent-dropwdowns-chosen-gem)

```
        @Html.DropDownList("divisionIds", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DivisionList, null, new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect" })
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //$("#divisionIds").multipleSelect()
            $("#divisionIds").chosen()
            $("#divisionIds").on('change', function (e) {
                //alert($("#divisionIds").val());
                var val = $("#divisionIds").val();
                var subItems = "";
                //alert(val);
                $.getJSON("/Home/GetFilteredPostingGroups/" + val, null, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        subItems += "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>"
                    });

                    alert(subItems);

                    //here...
                    $("#postingGroupIds").empty();
                    $("#postingGroupIds").append(subItems);
                    $("#postingGroupIds").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#postingGroupIds").change();


                });
            });
        </script>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.DropDownList("postingGroup")*@
            @Html.DropDownList("postingGroupIds", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PostingGroupList, null, new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect" })
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#postingGroupIds").chosen()
            </script>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="Command" value="@Command.Viewing" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

What is wrong?
Or how to do this in other way, maybe other controls?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you don't apply the `chosen` plugin?

Comment: Plug-in control is good! Issue will be there in success callback `data`. See the data in console.log(data) and show us how is the data look like. I created one fiddle for this [Here is the Working Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/ep37owwr/)

Comment: thanks, Venkata. Good sample, i found a problem. 
When i put my javascript code into $(function) () {...} it starts working. I am not good in javascript, tell why it works suchwise?

Comment: I'll add that one in answer with description with recommendations, so that you can understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chosen jQuery-Plug-In](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is Good. I'm glad that [Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/ep37owwr/) helped you to fix the issue.

As per the comments you've realized that it is working after moving the script block into `DOM-Ready` handler function body. and you asked that you want to know more about it.

**Here is the description:**
For your case `DOMContentLoaded`/`jQuery-DOM-Ready` event-handler is right place.
We can also run immediate executable script code on window load event-handler as well.

Here we should understand one thing with jQuery and its plug-ins:
$(=jQuery) or its plug-ins or relevant html elements wont be ready until document-ready event fires, so always we must keep the JavaScript code in ready handler body block as below that needs to be run immediately after rendering the html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Your immediate executable JS Code should be here
    });

    //OR like below shortcut syntax

    $(function(){
        //Your immediate executable JS Code should be here
    });
</script>
```

> **Why should we put the JavaScript in *[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event handler(i.e., [jQuery's document-ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)* event-handler block** that immediately run/executes in a html script fragment?

The [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event is fired when the `document` has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).

Here is the sample script with plain html from Mozilla dev docs

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
</script>
```

**[$(handler) is jQuery's method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to detect the above content loading state**
*Here is the description from [jQuery learning docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):* A page can't be manipulated safely until the `document` is `ready`. `jQuery` detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Answer (score 0):

> Or how to do this in other way, maybe other controls?

An option for you if you are willing to look at 3rd party tools is Kendo UI. They have something exactly for this and its really easy to implement:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I has two dropdowns,
first:

```
<td>
           @Html.DropDownList("divisionIds", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DivisionList, null, new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect" })
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $("#divisionIds").chosen();
                    $("#divisionIds").on('change', function (e) {
                        var val = $("#divisionIds").val();
                        var subItems = "";
                        $.getJSON("/Home/GetFilteredPostingGroups/" + val, null, function (data) {
                            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                                subItems += "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>"
                            });
                            $("#postingGroupIds").empty().append(subItems).trigger("chosen:updated");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
</td>
```

and second:

```
<td>
     @Html.DropDownList("postingGroupIds", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PostingGroupList, null, new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect" })
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#postingGroupIds").chosen();
            });
     </script>
</td>
```

when i put (in second dropdown) the code: ** $("#postingGroupIds").chosen(); ** into $(function ( .. here ..) { } **it starts working.**

thanks.